# How to know the application name which the user was using?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, custom-keyboard

I am a beginner in the field of android development.
I am trying to build a keyboard app in the android studio so that the user can use it for typing in applications like Whatsapp, Facebook...etc
My query is if the user is using this app for typing some text, is it possible to know in which application he is typing?
If it is not possible is there any other way to know about the application which was being used by the user?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is possible using the ActivityManager.

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
```

...

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = Objects.requireNonNull(activityManager).getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Yes, well ... at least once upon a time this would have worked but this has not been the case for some years now, see the [documentation for ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningTasks(int)). The post you linked has been published only one year ago - which tells us not to trust content from this site in the future ;-)